# "openssl_pkey_new(): private key length is too short" on php artisan passport:install

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, installation, laravel-passport

I get following error while creating client keys with `php artisan passport:install`

> openssl_pkey_new(): private key length is too short; it needs to
>   be at least 384 bits, not 0

Error happens in `\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php: 560`

```
  557:             if (isset($this->configFile)) {
  558:                 $config['config'] = $this->configFile;
  559:             }
  560:             $rsa = openssl_pkey_new(array('private_key_bits' => $bits) + $config);
  561:             openssl_pkey_export($rsa, $privatekey, null, $config);
  562:             $publickey = openssl_pkey_get_details($rsa);
```

I can't find any information about increasing key length in google. How can I fix this?

Comment: I used `php artisan passport:install --length=2048` too. Result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the latest Laravel Passport. Either downgrade to 6.0.3 or try using `php artisan passport:install --length=256` temporarily.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/757

Comment: I mentioned before --length not working. Problem is $bits varible. Somewhere it setting $bits = 0